# Access to fetch at request from origin has been blocked by CORS policy. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, fetch, gatsby

I've got this error when I am fetching data from the api

Access to fetch at 'https://app.api.com/api/products/48' from origin has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

This is how I am making a request to the api in code.

```
 async function getProductdata(){
    setIsLoading(true);
    const secret = process.env.SECRET <--
    const request = await fetch(`https://app.myapi.com/api/products/${data.productsCsv.id}`, {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `Basic ${btoa(secret)}`,
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        }
    }).then((request => request.json()))
      .then(data => setProductData(data))
      .catch(err=>console.log(err))  
      .finally(() => setIsLoading(false))
}
```

This works completely fine when I change my environment variable "process.env.SECRET" to an actual hardcoded value. I had make sure in my CI/CD tool that I have this environment variable setup before attempting a build.
Not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: So... if hardcoding the secret "fixes" it, i highly suspect your "cors" error is just a symptom (and/or evidence of a faulty error handler), both at the api-end

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue with environment variable declaration in CI/CD

When you're using Gatsby, for all client side javascript We have to add GATSBY_ as a prefix in our Variable declaration in CI/CD

Ref: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/local-development/environment-variables/#client-side-javascript

Answer (score -1):

The problem comes from the API side, you need to allow CORS on your API serveur.

If your script is PHP, that's :

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With");
```

Your can easily google others language équivalents, but i'm sure that's your solution.

Note, for safety, add only mandatory website on "Access-Control-Allow-Origin".